# How to call a custom model from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I do not wish to save anything to a database, so created a **model** written as this :

```
class Calculation
  attr_accessor :name, :docket_num, :payments

  def calculate
    ...
```

I call it in my **controller** like this :

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

  def calculator
    @calc = Calculation.new
  end
```

In my **view** as this :

```
= form_for @calc do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :judgement_balance
    %br/
    = f.text_field :judgement_balance
    ...
```

But it appears I am doing this wrong, because it return this :

```
undefined method `model_name' for Calculation:Class
```

**1st Question :** Anyone know what I am missing?

**2nd Question :** How can one transfer the params to a second view and perform a calculation with saving anything to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rails3:

```
class Calculation
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def name
    "Calculation"
  end
end

> c = Calculation.new
> c.model_name
 => "Calculation"
```

That should get your form working.  I don't understand your second question - you can instantiate a new Calculation object based on the params when the form is submitted and perform the calculation.

Comment: Hmm thanks for pointing me the right direction, though it seems better to write `extend ActiveModel::Naming` .